# Discord bot.py will not run with await bot.start()

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to put a command in a separate file in a folder called cogs. I have been trying to find resources however most are for cogs1.0 and an older version of discord.py

In this one I put `bot.load_extension()` inside `async def main()` because it wanted to await, and I ran the `main` with `asyncio`.

However it still does not work. Below are my codes without the commands

**bot.py**

```
import cmath
import asyncio
from colorsys import rgb_to_hls
import math
import os
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext.commands import cooldown, BucketType

 
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")

async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.load_extension("cogs.cog_function")
        await bot.start('TOKEN')

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(main())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

**cog_function.py**

```
import math
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class CogFunction(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    # commands in here

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(CogFunction(bot))
```

It gave me no error, no tracebacks, etc.
The only line in the Terminal is
`PS C:\Users\[MY USERNAME]\Desktop\Discord Bot> & C:/Users/[MY USERNAME]/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/[MY USERNAME]/Desktop/Discord Bot/bot.py"` with no additional errors or anything

I tried to remove `await bot.start('TOKEN')` but obviously it did not work, giving me

`Unclosed connector connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000247D2BEB220>, 4735.609)]'] connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000247D2BB9400>`

I also tried removing `bot.run(TOKEN)` but it did not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output of the program?

Comment: The expected behaviour of the program would be that the bot logs in. For example, 

2023-05-11 11:36:16 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2023-05-11 11:36:20 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: [ID number]).
We have logged in as [Discord bot name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `asyncio.run` more than once, behind the scenes, `bot.run` also uses it, that's why it's called 2 times. To fix it, you can simply move the `load_extension` into `bot.setup_hook` which is a new hook that's called before the bot runs:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")


async def setup_hook():
    await bot.load_extension("cogs.cog_function")


bot.setup_hook = setup_hook


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, it worked. One other thing that bugged me was that I did not use `self` inside the parameter of the commands in the cog file, maybe it would be helpful for someone else happened to stumble upon this.